# Extraneous empty row after header

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('index', 'name', 'age'), ('idx01', 'John', 23), ('idx02', 'Marc', 32), ('idx03', 'Helena', 12)]

columns = data.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).set_index(columns[0])
print(df)
```

Which produces:

```
         name  age
index               <----- Where is this row coming from?
idx01    John   23
idx02    Marc   32
idx03  Helena   12
```

I do not understand where is the empty `index`  row coming from. Is this a header, or a data row? Why is it being generated? It is *just* an empty row, but other dataframes (generated with other methods) in my code do not have that empty row. I would like to make sure my data is not corrupted somehow.

Comment: It is no empty row. Try remove `index.name` by `df.index.name=None` and no empty row.

Comment: @jezrael: Thanks! Aha, it's the name of the index! I assume `set_index` sets that too.

Comment: Yes, if you set index from column with name, `index.name` is `column name`

Answer (score 3):

It is no empty row. Try remove `index.name` by `df.index.name=None` and no empty row.  If you [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column with `name`, `index.name` is column name like `index` in this sample.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [('index', 'name', 'age'), 
        ('idx01', 'John', 23), 
        ('idx02', 'Marc', 32), 
        ('idx03', 'Helena', 12)]

columns = data.pop(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).set_index(columns[0])
print(df)
         name  age
index             
idx01    John   23
idx02    Marc   32
idx03  Helena   12

df.index.name=None
print(df)
         name  age
idx01    John   23
idx02    Marc   32
idx03  Helena   12
```